# Binding data to a bootstrap card from database table

Tags: c#, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, webforms, bootstrap-4

I am working on one student project (Online Shopping). My project details, code behind and all are mentioned in this code line.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="OnlineShopping.SiteMaster" %>
```

I got one idea that i want to show the product details for instance (see the code sample below) into bootstrap cards.

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=onlineShopping;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            Byte[] imgByte = (Byte[])ViewState["TheImage"];
            string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imgByte, 0, imgByte.Length);
            ProImage.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String;
            string sqlStatement;
            SqlCommand manageCommand;
            sqlStatement = "insert into ProductTable values (@ProName, @ProPrice, @ProDescription, @ProPic)";
            sqlStatement += "  SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);";
            manageCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement, connection);
            //manageCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProId", Convert.ToInt32(txtProId.Text.Trim()));
            manageCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProName", txtProName.Text.Trim());
            manageCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProPrice", txtProPrice.Text.Trim());
            manageCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProDescription", txtProDescription.Text.Trim());
            manageCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProPic", imgByte);

            connection.Open();
            int count = manageCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Each product should come in new card as how much products i will add, all product should come in bootstrap cards to my dashboard, and the card itself should contain hyperlink as when the user clicks the card, it should redirect to some page. Hope you got my views, please answer and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Repeater` control for data binding.

Please review [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx) and example of usage [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5089e0/how-to-use-repeater-control-in-Asp-Net/) and [here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Repeater-control-Tutorial-with-example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx).

Of course you need use your bootstrap layout inside `Repeater` control.